# Make div not clickable in CSS while still controlling cursor

Tags: css

The best way I know to make a div not clickable with CSS is to use:

```
  pointer-events: none,
```

But then the cursor will always be the default one:

```
pointer-events: none;
cursor: not-allowed; // THIS WON'T DO ANYTHING
```

Is there a way to achieve both in CSS (and hopefully without Javascript)? Setting just the `cursor` will show the div as not clickable while it still is.

Comment: Maybe the "proper" way to implement it is with `disabled` property.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is use the `:before` pseudo-element to create an invisible overlay over the div that prevents clicking. You can also add to this pseudo-element the cursor property `not-allowed` to visually indicate that the div is not clickable.

Here an example:

```css
/* Optional div style */
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: grey;
}

.not-clickable {
  position: relative;
}

.not-clickable:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}

.not-clickable:hover:before {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); /* Optional hover effect */
  cursor: not-allowed;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="not-clickable">You can't click me</div>
```